# How to prevent imports of packages from all classes except one class?

Tags: java, import, checkstyle

I migrate my code from Common Collection 3 to Common Collection 4
After the migration I want to prevent imports of Common Collection 3 packages in all classes except one class.

(Unfortunately I do not have time to migrate this class).

I have found this but I can not find how to configure exclude list:
http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#IllegalImport

Is it possible to configure checkstyle to exclude classes?

Other tools that can do it?

Comment: Remove the v3 from your dependencies, fix what doesn't compile anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ok with configuring Checkstyle rules to achieve this, then you just need to use a more complex option (IllegalImport has only one parameter - illegalpackage):

[ImportControl](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html#ImportControl).

Comment: Do you know if possible to use the similar configuration for Checkstyle Plugin: 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Checkstyle+Plugin

Comment: This tutorial explains how to configure your Checkstyle plugin for Jenkins with custom rules: https://dustplanet.de/howto-use-your-own-checkstyle-rules-in-your-jenkinsmaven-job/

Answer (score 0):

Remove from your `classpath` anything that you don't want imported.  Then, it will error on those imports when you are compiling.